# Using switch with subclasses?

Tags: java, switch-statement

Is it possible to use switch and having as cases different subclasses ? I want to use switch instead of several if statements. I have an abstract class called instruction and subclasses with different types. So i want each case to be a different subclass. like :

```
switch (instruction){
    case instruction1:
    case instruction2:
    case instruction3:
}
```

etc
as said instruction1,2,3 are subclasses of same class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, switch only works on numeric values and enums. (In Java 7 it will work on strings too.)

It sounds like you should probably have a method overridden in the different subclasses... or *possibly* use enums (which can still override methosds).

If that doesn't help, please give more information about what you're trying to do - ideally with an example.

Comment: The project im working on is a simulator. I read instructions from a text and then execute them. Now each subclass represents different type of instruction and has different methods.The abstract class doesnt have any methods. Now on my method i want to check what instruction i have and then do what the instruction says. I started doing it as if-else with casting i just wondered if there is a "nicer" way to do it.

Comment: After reading from text the instructions go to an array and that should not change .

Comment: @latusaki: If you're already creating the appropriate instance, it really sounds like you should have an `execute()` method or something similar, and override it in each subclass.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you'd want to use runtime polymorphism instead.

Simply call a method on the object and implement it differently in each subclass.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility (somewhat of a hack) would be to create an enum in the superclass and an abstract method getEnum() which would be implemented by each subclass. The subclasses would then each return a different instance for the enum. As in:

```
abstract class Super
{
enum Type {ONE, TWO, THREE};

abstract Type getType();
}

public class ChildOne extends Super
{
public Type getType()
{
return Type.ONE;
}
}

public class ChildTwo extends Super
{
public Type getType()
{
return Type.TWO;
}
}
```

Then you could do:

```
Super someClass;
switch(someClass.getType())
{
case ONE:
//domSomething
break;

case TWO:
//domSomeOtherThin
break;
//...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, in Java you can only use integers as switch conditions (*edit*: and `enums` where `ordinal()` is used). The solution you are looking for (instead of nasty `if-else` with plenty of `instanceof` operators) is the [Visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Jon's response: in Java enums are objects, so you *might* be able to achieve what you're trying to do by using enums, depending on exactly what that is. That said, it's likely to be not a very elegant approach.

Answer (score 0):

Using `if-statements` with `Superclass.isAssignableFrom(Subclass)` or `Subclass.isAssignableFrom(SuperClass)` as a condition depending on what you want to achieve. Might be a good substitute for what you're looking to achieve with  `switch statements`.

Or alternatively use `instanceof` operators instead of the `isAssignableFrom()` function.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably be happy to know we know have *Pattern Matching for Switch
Switch Expressions - Type Patterns*: https://openjdk.org/jeps/441

```
// from Java 17 as preview & from Java 21 as stable

static String formatterPatternSwitch(Object obj) {
    return switch (obj) {
        case Integer i -> String.format("int %d", i);
        case Long l    -> String.format("long %d", l);
        case Double d  -> String.format("double %f", d);
        case String s  -> String.format("String %s", s);
        default        -> obj.toString();
    };
}
```